# Serial byte input to tkinter combobox values

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, serial-port

python 2nd program -- (lot to learn) I am trying to read serial port information in byte format into a string and then use that string to populate the 'values' of a tkinter combobox which will then be used to select a def type function for serial output of selected info output to the same serial port. Only need to read serial port data on program start but will write selection back to serial port multiple times. I plan on using a variation of cb.bind('<>', comboclick) -> to trigger a def function to send serial data out.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import serial

d2 = []
data = []
def get_serial():
    global d2
    global data
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)
    ser.write(b'$$\n')
    while True:
    #data = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
        if data == 'ok':
            break
        data = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').replace('\r\n',',')
    #print(data)
        d2 = data
        print(data)
    
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Great Britain Basketball')
root.geometry('800x449+300+130')
root.configure(bg='#072462')

#def variable and store based on selection
def comboclick(event):
    global select_sheet # Setting select_sheet to global, so it can be modified
    select_sheet = cb.get()

#I am setting here the same value of cb.current(), so if the user doesn't change it, you still #get an output.
select_sheet = 'Mon'
get_serial() # +++++++++++++ doesn't work ++ goes into loop? +++++++++
#create combobox
#cb = ttk.Combobox(root, value=('Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs'))
cb = ttk.Combobox(root, value=d2) #-- This should populate combobox values ???
cb.current(0)
cb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', comboclick)
cb.pack()

#set close window button
button_close = tk.Button(root, width=35, text='Close Programme', command=root.quit, 
                      fg='#C51E42', bg='#B4B5B4', borderwidth=1).pack()

root.mainloop()

print(select_sheet)
```

1st time asking question so will do better in future requests

I have tried all types of string formatting, string conversions, byte conversions but I am missing something (probably simple). Code above is a modified version of a previous answered question. Serial out not written yet.
Tried cb = ttk.Combobox(root, config(value=d2)) as suggested in another post - no luck just looping?

Comment: There is an infinity loop inside `get_serial()`, so how can you expect the function returns?

Comment: Are you suggesting while data != 'ok' which is at the the end of the serial transmission and should end the loop? tried versions of while and keep getting data is not defined. Can't use a count index because data will vary in length. Any suggestions on while loop that will test for serial transmission terminated with 'ok'

Comment: changed while statement so not to loop.  Still can't figure out how to get data into checkbox 'values' -- some version of cb = ttk.Combobox(root, value=str(d2)) # How to assign a list/string?

Comment: You're missing `.append`. Should be `d2.append(select_sheet)`

Comment: thanks for the reply. not sure where you want the d2.append(selectsheet). Really new to python so more verbose explanation would be appreciated thanks

Comment: In line 18, `d2 = data`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the value of `data` *after reading it from the serial port*.  Also it is better to get those values before creating the GUI.

Below is the modified code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import serial

COMPORT = "/dev/ttyACM0"
BAUDRATE = 115200

def get_serial():
    values = []
    with serial.Serial(COMPORT, BAUDRATE) as ser:
        ser.write(b"$$\n")
        while True:
            data = ser.readline().decode("utf-8").strip()
            if data == "ok":
                break
            values.append(data) # save the data into values
    return values

# get the values before creating the GUI
print("getting values from serial port ...")
values = get_serial()
print(values)

# create the GUI
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Great Britain Basketball")
root.geometry("800x449+300+130")
root.configure(bg="#072462")

def comboclick(event):
    global select_sheet
    select_sheet = cb.get()
    # send the selected sheet via the serial port
    with serial.Serial(COMPORT, BAUDRATE) as ser:
        ser.write(f"{select_sheet}\n".encode("utf-8"))

cb = ttk.Combobox(root, values=values)
cb.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", comboclick)
cb.pack()

tk.Button(root, width=35, text="Close Programme", command=root.destroy,
          fg="#C51E42", bg="#B4B5B4", bd=1).pack()

root.mainloop()
print(select_sheet)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help and the education !!!!! I have stared at my code for 4 days prior to posting. Can't thank you enough!!!